# CheckedList Box doesn't have displayMember property?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I am so confused, I want to use the displayMember propery of the CheckedListbox in C# but it doesn't sems to have one?

Does anyone know if I have to add or impelement any thing before being able to use it?

Many thanks in advance. 
Cheers

Comment: It should be there. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb.aspx) if you are working with WinForms

Comment: I know it should be there but is not, is so strange!!! I used the property for LisBox no problem, but CheckedListBox doesn't have it?? and control+Space doesn't even have that in the list. I though may I am doing something silly with assembly reference but that is not the case either. :(

Comment: @Kevin_Dingo, are you working with Windows Forms?

Comment: @Andrei Yes I am using Windows Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayMember` property is decorated with [EditorBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx):

```
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)
```

which makes it invisible for the IntelliSense. But it does not prevent you from using it - just type this property in the editor, and your code should compile fine.